# When searching for a nodes run list using pychef I get an empty runlist

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

so I'm using the following code to get a node run list

```
with ChefAPI('http://localhost:4000', 'my.pem', 'admin'):
     n = Node('web1')
     print n.run_list
```

But I keep getting an empty run list, but it works when I try and get the environment of the node.  I don't get any errors it just shows []. Does anyone maybe have an idea why it is doing this?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

That URL doesn't sound right. You need to access Chef Server via the correct API URL, usually `https://something`. 4000 is an internal port for just one of the components (normally).

Comment: O sorry should have said that is just example sorry, i have the actual chef server link in my parameters

Comment: Are you sure the node is named like that? Names more commonly FQDNs so something more like web1.foo.com. See the output of knife node list to confirm.

Comment: No, still get an empty run list.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output from knife node list.